# Re-direct to the previous url using UrlReferrer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I have stuck in a step where I need to redirect user to the originated page after login or sign up.

I know that whenever action is performed it keeps the originated url in UrlReferrer.
And my problem here is I want keep the orginated and doesn't want to change this during the sign up process or login process.
For example, the use is in the page called 'A' and wants to sign up and goes through the sign up process. During my sign up process, the use goes through'Sign_Up_Step1' and 'Sign_Up_Step2' page.
By the time user gets to 'Sign_Up_Step2' page, UrlReferrer will have the url for 'Sign_Up_Step1' page as it was the previous page.

Is there anyway to keep the originated page 'A' for this example?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to persist it in some way. Persisting a querystring over several pages can be clumsy so your best bet is probably to use a cookie:

At the start of your process:

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    var refCookie = new Cookie("ReferralUrl");
    refCookie.Value = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
    refCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(refCookie);
}
```

In the controller action at the end of your signup process:

```
var refCookie = Request.Cookies["ReferralUrl"];
if (refCookie != null)
    return Redirect(refCookie.Value);
```

You'll probably also want to handle the event where there is no referrer by setting a default return URL or something.

Comment: This is a good answer but I have a further problem here. 
Let's say I put the code to add the urlreferrer to the cookie in both 'log in' and 'Sign_Up_Step1'. 
And the user starts from the page 'A' and goes to the 'Sign_Up_Step1' page. 
At this stage cookie keeps the page 'A' from the UrlReferrer, but if the user goes to the 'log in' page from the 'sign_up_step_1' the cookie gets updated with 'Sign_up_Step1' page. 
How should I prevent this ? Should I code to ignore updating the cookie if it's from a specific controller ?

Comment: Include a check for the cookie and don't set it if it already exists? Then you can force it to expire at the end of the process to reset it.